# magento: how to add Multiple Sizes & different quantity for simple products

Tags: magento, size

i wish to add qty to the each size in magento simple product, here, i have configured size in custom option as it doesn't have the option to add qty.

formygalaxy

Answer (score 3):

What are you trying to achieve is not achievable with simple product.
You should use configurable product instead.
You can read about configurable products [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/tutorial-creating-a-configurable-product), for example.

Comment: Perhaps this plugin could help ; http://www.mageworx.com/advanced-product-options-magento-extension.html